# Rotate Earth around sun, and moon around earth

Tags: opengl, transformation, c

**SOLVED:**
I'm trying to rotate the moon around the earth.

Which this part of the code only the earth is rotated around the sun, how can I make the axis to be center of earth's object? I thought about translateF(2,0,0) which doesn't work. Here's the part :

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(earthR, 100, 100);
glPopMatrix();

//glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(2.5, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(moonR, 100, 100);
glPopMatrix();
```

And full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include"GL/glut.h"

//global constants
#define ANIMATION_DELAY 20
#define PI 3.14

//function declerations
void drawingCB(void);
void reshapeCB(int width, int height);
void keyboardCB(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void keyboardSpecialCB(int key, int x, int y);
void TimerCB(int value);
GLubyte *readBMP(char *imagepath, int *width, int *height);
GLuint generateTextures(char *imagepath);
void TerminationErrorFunc(char *ErrorString);


//globals
int ObjectRotatingAngle = 0;
int ViewPointAngle1 = 0, ViewPointAngle2 = 0;
int FOVy = 60;
int OnOff = 1;
float sunR = 0.7;
float earthR = 0.4;
float moonR = 0.25;

//textures gloabals
int BoxTextureIds[6];
#define SKY_RIGHT 0
#define SKY_LEFT  1
#define SKY_UP    2
#define SKY_DOWN  3
#define SKY_BACK  4
#define SKY_FRONT 5
int TeapotTextureId;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    //initizlizing GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    //initializing window
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(900, 100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("3D world");

    //enable depth testing
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //registering callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(drawingCB);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeCB);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardCB);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboardSpecialCB);
    glutTimerFunc(ANIMATION_DELAY, TimerCB, 0);

    //specify textures and setting Specific texture parameters
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_RIGHT] = generateTextures("posx.bmp");
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_LEFT] = generateTextures("negx.bmp");
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_UP] = generateTextures("posy.bmp");
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_DOWN] = generateTextures("negy.bmp");
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_BACK] = generateTextures("posz.bmp");
    BoxTextureIds[SKY_FRONT] = generateTextures("negz.bmp");
    TeapotTextureId = generateTextures("tex3.bmp");

    //setting Global texture parameters
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); //determine how texture mapping interacts   
                                                                //with shading modes. Can be: GL_MODULATE or GL_BLEND or GL_REPLACE 
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //starting main loop
    glutMainLoop();
}


GLuint generateTextures(char *imagepath)
{
    GLubyte *ImageData;
    int width, height;
    GLuint TextureID;

    //reading the image
    ImageData = readBMP(imagepath, &width, &height);

    //Giving a texture ID
    glGenTextures(1, &TextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID);

    //Assign Image as a texture 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ImageData);

    //freeing image memory
    free(ImageData);

    //setting Specific texture parameters 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // GL_REPEAT or GL_CLAMP
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // GL_LINEAR or GL_NEAREST
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return TextureID;
}




void drawingCB(void)
{
    GLenum er;
    double D = 10;
    double d = 0.02;
    double R = 5;

    //clearing the background
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //initializing modelview transformation matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //setting viewing angle
    gluLookAt(R*cos((double)ViewPointAngle1*PI / 180), 4, R*sin((double)ViewPointAngle1*PI / 180), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    //drawing a box
    //right
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_RIGHT]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(+D - d, -D, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(+D - d, -D, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(+D - d, +D, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(+D - d, +D, -D);
    glEnd();
    //left
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_LEFT]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-D + d, -D, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-D + d, -D, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-D + d, +D, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-D + d, +D, +D);
    glEnd();
    //up
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_UP]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-D, +D - d, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(+D, +D - d, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(+D, +D - d, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-D, +D - d, +D);
    glEnd();
    //down
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_DOWN]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-D, -D + d, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(+D, -D + d, +D);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(+D, -D + d, -D);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-D, -D + d, -D);
    glEnd();
    //back
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_BACK]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-D, -D, -D + d);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(+D, -D, -D + d);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(+D, +D, -D + d);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-D, +D, -D + d);
    glEnd();
    //front
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BoxTextureIds[SKY_FRONT]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(+D, -D, +D - d);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-D, -D, +D - d);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-D, +D, +D - d);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(+D, +D, +D - d);
    glEnd();


    if (OnOff)
    {
        //rotating the object

        printf("ObjectRotatingAngle:%d, Viewing points angles: %d,%d\n", ObjectRotatingAngle, ViewPointAngle1, ViewPointAngle2);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TeapotTextureId);
        glTexGenf(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);//GL_OBJECT_LINEAR GL_EYE_LINEAR GL_SPHERE_MAP
        glTexGenf(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
        glutSolidSphere(sunR, 100, 100);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    }
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(earthR, 100, 100);
    glPopMatrix();

    //glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(2.5, 0, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(moonR, 100, 100);
    glPopMatrix();


    //swapping buffers and displaying
    glutSwapBuffers();

    //check for errors
    er = glGetError();  //get errors. 0 for no error, find the error codes in: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error
    if (er) printf("error: %d\n", er);
}



void reshapeCB(int width, int height)
{
    float zNear, zFar;

    //define our ortho
    zNear = 1; zFar = 40;

    //update viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    //clear the transformation matrices (load identity)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //projection
    gluPerspective(FOVy, 1, zNear, zFar);
}


void keyboardCB(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case '+':
        FOVy = FOVy - 1;
        reshapeCB(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '-':
        FOVy = FOVy + 1;
        reshapeCB(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case ' ':
        OnOff = !OnOff;
        break;
    }
}


void keyboardSpecialCB(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        ViewPointAngle1 = (ViewPointAngle1 + 360 - 1) % 360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        ViewPointAngle1 = (ViewPointAngle1 + 360 + 1) % 360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        ViewPointAngle2 = (ViewPointAngle2 + 360 - 1) % 360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        ViewPointAngle2 = (ViewPointAngle2 + 360 + 1) % 360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    }
}


void TimerCB(int value)
{
    ObjectRotatingAngle = (ObjectRotatingAngle + 360 + 1) % 360;

    // reassign to the timer event again        
    glutTimerFunc(ANIMATION_DELAY, TimerCB, value);

    // call redisplay   
    glutPostRedisplay();
}





// Function to load bmp file
// buffer for the image is allocated in this function, you should free this buffer
GLubyte *readBMP(char *imagepath, int *width, int *height)
{
    unsigned char header[54]; // Each BMP file begins by a 54-bytes header
    unsigned int dataPos;     // Position in the file where the actual data begins
    unsigned int imageSize;   // = width*height*3
    unsigned char * data;
    unsigned char tmp;
    int i;

    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(imagepath, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        TerminationErrorFunc("Image could not be opened\n");
    }

    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) { // If not 54 bytes read : problem
        TerminationErrorFunc("Not a correct BMP file\n");
    }

    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        TerminationErrorFunc("Not a correct BMP file\n");
    }

    // Read ints from the byte array
    dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    *width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    *height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

    // Some BMP files are misformatted, guess missing information
    if (imageSize == 0)
        imageSize = *width**height * 3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
    if (dataPos == 0)
        dataPos = 54; // The BMP header is done that way

                      // Create a buffer
    data = malloc(imageSize * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
    fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);


    //swap the r and b values to get RGB (bitmap is BGR)
    for (i = 0; i<*width**height; i++)
    {
        tmp = data[i * 3];
        data[i * 3] = data[i * 3 + 2];
        data[i * 3 + 2] = tmp;
    }


    //Everything is in memory now, the file can be closed
    fclose(file);

    return data;
}



void TerminationErrorFunc(char *ErrorString)
{
    char string[256];
    printf(ErrorString);
    fgets(string, 256, stdin);     // warning: unsafe (see fgets instead)

    exit(0);
}
```

**SOLVED:**

```
//The earth
glColor3f(0.4901, 0.8117, 0.6705);
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(earthR, 100, 100);

//Rotating the moon around the earth
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle * 2, 0, 1, 0.0);
glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(moonR, 100, 100);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Don't edit your solution to the question. Instead, you have to post the solution as an answer to the question which you can then accept.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I didn't!! I just added the solution.

Comment: Yes you did. Your solution (the answer to your question) is in the question body, which is not the correct place for it.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Ohh... right. sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
//The earth
glColor3f(0.4901, 0.8117, 0.6705);
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle, 0.0, 1, 0.0);
glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(earthR, 100, 100);

//Rotating the moon around the earth
glRotated((GLdouble)ObjectRotatingAngle * 2, 0, 1, 0.0);
glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(moonR, 100, 100);
glPopMatrix();
```